# Ubuntu 18.04.1 desktop another graphical issues

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, text-mode

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 18.04.1 desktop edition on my lenovo ideapad z500 laptop and i'm facing graphical issues. After the grub menu during live USB boot, the image on the monitor shrinks vertically 1/3 of the screen height and the text isn't readable. 
I've read other posts about Ubuntu graphical issues and haven't found a solution to my problem.

I've tried using **nomodeset** kernel parameter alongside with other **i915** and **nouveau** parameters variations and it didn't help. Also i've tried setting **gfxpayload** to *text* that gave no effect either.

Could anyone please help to resolve this issue? Or at least clarify if it is possible to boot live Ubuntu 18.04.1 kernel in pure text mode without gfx?

P.S. Using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> i can see TTY changing but it doesn't do any changes to the graphics.

Answer (score 0):

ctrl-alt-f2 changes to a tty in text mode.
If you still cannot see anything its more complicated

First check which graphics card you have (there are 5 different ones possible on the z500)
then check your native (and other)video resolutions.

Try the gfxmode setting (you can put a comma separated list there also) e.g.:

```
set gfxmode=640x480,auto
```

details here https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/html_node/gfxmode.html

this tells you how to make it permanent:
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1794722

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

set this variable to the desired value

```
GRUB_GFXMODE="800x600"
```

then do

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment, but i believe the text mode refers to VGA text mode and Crtl+Alt+f2 doesn't change the gfx mode to text, it just shows the tty console in gfx mode. I've tried different resolutions and since it doesn't help i decided to switch to Debian distribution. That worked for me.

Comment: Oh yes  that seems to have changed in 18.04 or even before?!?
I remember the change in display resolutions from a while ago and didn't notice that the mode is not changed anymore.